# How can I put sprite backgound image inside the container?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I have a sprite image which is a contian of two images.
But they are always bigger than the container, I want to fix/put them inside the parent container. How can I fit images without increasing parent size?

[image: background parent has a red border]

HTML:

```
<body>
<div><span class="affiliate-sprite-60"></span></div>
<div><span class="affiliate-sprite-40"></span></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.affiliate-sprite-60
{
background:url('affiliate-sprite.jpg') 0px -1px;
width:799px;height:440px;
display:inline-block;
}

.affiliate-sprite-40
{
background:url('affiliate-sprite.jpg') -799px -0px;
width:783px;height:441px;
display:inline-block;
}
div {
width: 600px;
border: 2px solid red;
}
```

This is the original image:
[image]

Comment: By using things like `background-size` and `background-position`? You seem to only use some bare positioning and nothing else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS image spriting doesn't involve resizing the images.
Indeed one of the benefits of CSS spriting is that it can help reduce the CPU load on the browser because it avoids the need for the browser to resize individual images before rendering them.

You have two options:

1. Resize the images within the sprite with an image editing tool
2. Increase the width of the parent container.

Comment: This does not work in different sizes

Comment: you should have different sprite images for all the sizes you need and hide or display them depending on your needs.